# Get 'frequency table' of many columns with R repetitive coding

Tags: r, statistics, frequency

I have a dataset (data.frame) named 'test', and there are 52 columns(predictors) named T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6,.......T50.

I want to extract the frequency table of each column.

I know there is a function for it named 'freq'.

Then, how can I get 50 frequency tables without manual 52 times coding.

Comment on it if you have any idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

We can loop over the columns with `lapply` and apply `table` to get the frequency count of each column

```
lapply(test, table)
```

We could also convert the columns to `factor` with `levels` specified as the `unique` elements in the dataset, and then apply the `table` so that the `list` elements can be `rbind` to create a `data.frame` or `matrix` (to keep the `length` of `list` element to be the same by not dropping the unused levels)

```
Un1 <- sort(unique(unlist(test)))
do.call(rbind, lapply(test, function(x) table(factor(x, levels=Un1))))
```

---

Or another option is `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(test)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
test <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:8, 8*50, replace=TRUE),
   ncol=50, dimnames=list(NULL, paste0("T", 1:50))) )
```